Fonts Not Rendering for Non-English Text in Node.js Video Rendering on Ubuntu EC2 Server
I'm working on a Node.js project that renders videos with text in multiple languages and fonts using the node-html-to-image library. Everything works perfectly on my local Windows machine, but when I deploy the project to an Ubuntu EC2 server, non-English text (like Chinese and Mandarin) doesn't render and appears as blank text in the videos.
The project is about video editing and in that project, the user will be able to add text to the video, the problem is in text rendering when I select non-English text it shows on the frontend, but hence the frontend is only responsible for sending the video data the rest will be handled by node.js script, which is deployed on AWS ubuntu EC2 machine, the video editing logic will be handled by this node.js script.
const textToImage = (layer) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {

            const textWidth = layer.size.width * multiplyNum
            const textHeight = layer.size.height * multiplyNum
            const textLeft = layer.position.left * multiplyNum
            const textTop = layer.position.top * multiplyNum
            const TextfontSize = parseInt(layer.style.fontSize) * multiplyNum
            let html = layer.src;

            if (layer.textToHighlight !== null && layer.textToHighlight !== undefined) {
                layer.textToHighlight.forEach((curElem) => {
                    html = html.replaceAll(curElem.text, `<span style="color:${curElem.color}; background:${curElem.background};">${curElem.text}</span>`);
                })
            }

            if (layer.innerCss != null && layer.innerCss != undefined) {
                html = `<span class="spanStyle" style="display: ${layer.innerCss.display};line-height: ${layer.innerCss.lineHeight}; padding: ${(layer.innerCss.padding)}; background: ${layer.innerCss.background}; -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone; box-decoration-break: clone;">${html}</span>`
            }
            else {
                html = `<span class="spanStyle">${html}</span>`
            }


            nodeHtmlToImage({
                output: rootDir + textCount + 'image.png',
                transparent: true,
                timeout: 60000,
                html: `<html>
                               <head>
                                  <meta charset="UTF-8">
                                  <script src ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js"></script>
                                   <script>
                                    WebFont.load({
                                        google: {
                                            families: ['${layer.style.fontFamily}']
                                        }
                                    });
                                    </script>
                                  <style> 

                                  *{
                                     box-sizing: border-box;
                                     margin: 0;
                                     padding:0;
                                    }
                                        
                                  body {
                                      width: ${mainWidth}px;
                                      height:${mainHeight}px;
                                    }
                                    
                                    .mystyle{
                                        background: ${layer.style.background};
                                        opacity: ${layer.style.opacity};
                                        border:${layer.style.border};
                                        box-shadow: ${layer.style.boxShadow};
                                        object-fit:${layer.style.objectFit};
                                        position: absolute;
                                        left: ${textLeft}px;
                                        top: ${textTop}px;
                                        width: ${textWidth};
                                        height: ${textHeight}px;
                                        text-align: ${layer.style.textAlign};
                                    }
                                    .spanStyle{
                                        color: ${layer.style.color};
                                        font-size: ${TextfontSize};
                                        font-family: ${layer.style.fontFamily};
                                        font-weight:${layer.style.fontWeight};                                   
                                        text-transform: ${layer.style.textTransform};
                                        text-decoration: ${layer.style.textDecoration}; 
                                        font-family: ${layer.style.fontFamily};
                                        font-style: ${layer.style.fontStyle};
                                        line-height: ${layer.style.lineHeight};
                                    }
                                    </style>
                                    </head>
                                    <body>
                                    <div class="mystyle">
                                         ${html}
                                    </div>
                                    </body>
                    </html>`,
            }).then(() => {
                resolve(rootDir + textCount + 'image.png');
                console.log(textCount + "text created successfully")
            })
                .catch((err) => {
                    resolve("");
                    console.error(err, "text failed to create");
                })
        } catch (error) {
            resolve("");
            console.log("text failed to create")
        }
    })
}

Steps Taken:
Installed necessary language packs on the Ubuntu server.
Verified network connectivity to Google Fonts.
Ensured Puppeteer dependencies are installed on the server.
Added logging to check if fonts are loading properly.
Observed Behavior:
On the local Windows environment, all languages render correctly.
On the Ubuntu EC2 server, non-English text appears blank.
here is the rendered video coming from the EC2 server

here is the frontend :

What could be causing the non-English text to not render on the Ubuntu EC2 server, and how can I resolve this issue? please answer as I already researched a lot and this can't be solved in the local environment the changes should be made on production. I want the video to be rendered correctly in all non-English languages like Chinese and Mandarin
